# Vlookup specific column that contains delimiters?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to vlookup/merge a column from two separate excel worksheets. I was able to successfuly get this to work, however the column that I am merging on, some of the cells contain multiple choices all separated by a semicolon ';'.
I need the code to be able to take the PDs from df1 see if they are in df2 and then map back what Number is in the same row as that PD. All of the PDs in df1 are separated, its the PDs in df2 that are either by itself or separated by delimiters.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('df1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('df2.xlsx')


columns = ['Number', 'PDs']
df2[columns]

dfmerge = df1.merge(df2[columns], on='PDs')
```

This runs, but for the cells in column PDs that have multiple options is not working.

```
row      PDs
0       2345
1       2675
2       8706
3       9045;4729;5392
4       3452
```

Here is an example of what PDs may look like.

Thank You

Comment: Because that's hot how `merge` works. If you want to merge on substrings you first have to create a column with the exact merging key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dict2=dict(zip(df2['row'],df2['PDs'])) # creating dictionary from row-PD columns ; This is the df with multiple PDs
list1=df1['PDs'].tolist()              #creating a list from PDs (single values)
final_dict=[]
for x in list1:              #loop to find values
    for k,v in dict2.items():
        if str(x) in v:
            final_dict.append(k)
df1['row']=final_dict       # assigning final dict as a new column in df1
```